# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-services

> SQL Server version: SQL Server 2016 SP2 GDR 2019 (KB4505220) -
>   13.0.5101.9 (x64) Issue: Analysis Services Processing Task: Error: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI, Version=13.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKey Token=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Actions Made so far:

1. Follow the option 3 assembly binding from this [site](https://www.sqlshack.com/top-4-options-for-fixing-microsoft-analysisservices-adomdclientui-dll-assembly-error-in-sql-server-2016/). Got this error after: `Analysis Service Processing Task: Error: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.analysisServices.AdomdClientUI.AdomdConnectionStringBuilder.IsAzure()'`
2. Install CU2 but during install it states that current SP2-GDR is latest

Any idea on the fix?

Comment: Telling us *where* and *when* you get this error would be helpful. I assume this error doesn't just start constantly appearing when your turn your PC on. Give us details of the actions you take.

Comment: sorry for that. Error occurs when running SSIS Package in SQL Server. 
Process:
1. Create SSIS Package with only Analysis Services Processing Task to call SSAS Cube
2. Run SSIS Package
3. Error will occur

Comment: But you don't tell us what that package does. We can't help you if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @Larnu As mention SSIS Package only has Analysis Service Processing Task <-- this is only calling the SSAS Cube. that is the only thing it does. error occur when SSIS is trying to communicate to SSAS

Comment: @Larnu please note that when you set Analysis Service Processing Task in SSIS you will need to put up the connection to SSAS with basic connection. So I thought if you have the idea on how that process work I dont need to expound it to a more detail on how i do the connection. It is totally a straight forward connection to SSAS Package

Answer (score 0):

We were able to fix the missing dll file when patching to SQL 2016 SP2 version 13.0.5622.0 (CU11 + Security Update) Release Date Feb 25, 2020.